# Range datetime on chart

Tags: c#, .net

I have a chart where the X axis gets the values ​​"DataHoraEvento" from my query, I set this axis to datetime, but in my chart the x-axis values ​​appear only hourly. I would like to know how I can shorten the time and show by these values ​​for example from minute to minute on my x axis.

[image]

Follow the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting;

public partial class graficos : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionStringSQL"].ConnectionString);
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 20 Log.ValorEntrada, Log.DataHoraEvento FROM Log INNER JOIN Equipamento ON Log.IDEquipamento = Equipamento.IDEquipamento INNER JOIN EntradaEstado ON Equipamento.IDEquipamento = EntradaEstado.IDEquipamento INNER JOIN Entrada ON EntradaEstado.IDEntrada = Entrada.IDEntrada WHERE Entrada.Descricao = 'Controle de acionamento do relé XR' AND Log.ValorEntrada IS NOT NULL ORDER BY DataHoraEvento DESC ");
        cmd.Connection = con;
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        Chart1.DataSource = dt;

        Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.Title = "Hora do Dia";

        if (Request.Form["descricao"] == "Tensão do carregador solar -de 11V à 14V")
            Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.Title = "Tensão (V)";
        else
            Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.Title = "Corrente (A)";



        Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "HH:mm:ss";
        Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.LineDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Dot;
        Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.LineDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Dot;
        Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.MajorGrid.LineColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkGray;
        Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.MajorGrid.LineDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Dot;
        Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.MajorGrid.LineColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkGray;
        Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.MajorGrid.LineDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Dot;


        Chart1.Series["Series1"].XValueType = ChartValueType.DateTime;
        Chart1.Series["Series1"].BorderWidth = 5;
        Chart1.Series["Series1"].XValueMember = "DataHoraEvento";
        Chart1.Series["Series1"].YValueMembers = "ValorEntrada";

        Chart1.Width = 800;
        Chart1.Height = 350;

        Chart1.DataBind();
        con.Close();
    }


}
```

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but you're setting your format to "HH:mm:ss", but you want to only see minutes? Just change your formatting.

Comment: No. Sorry, if I did not explain it well, now I posted a graphic image, I think it was better to understand, I wanted the x-axis values ​​not to be hourly, but rather I could define a range Minutes.

Comment: So you want to see 120 minutes  instead of 2 hours? - No such format afaik. You would need to convert x-values (or at least the labels) from datatime to doubles. Maybe you even need to go for customLabels..

Comment: I would like my x axis instead of showing 14:00, 15:00, 16:00, 17:00, 18:00 ... show 00:00, 00:30, 01:00, 01:30, 02 : 00, 02:30, 03:00, 03:30, 04:00 ... until 23:30.